# Calculating the sum of each digit of an Integer value

Tags: java, casting, integer, addition

In this exercise, I was suppose to grab any Integer and calculate the some of each digit.
I found the best way to do this would be to use the method below. Converting to a string and reading each character one by one and totaling the sum of each while in a for loop.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SommeChiffreNombre {

    /**
     * @param args
     * 
     * Demandez à l’usager d’entrer un nombre entier
     * Ensuite, calculez la somme de tous les chiffres de ce
     * nombre et affichez le résultat.
     * 
     * L’affichage obtenu doit être semblable aux suivants :
     * 
     * Entrez un nombre entier :
     * 5361
     * La somme des chiffres est : 15
     * 
     * 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            System.out.print("Entrez un nombre entier : ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int nb = in.nextInt();
            in.close();
            int somme = 0;

            for(int i=0;i<Integer.toString(nb).length();i++){
                char charVal = Integer.toString(nb).charAt(i);
                somme += Character.getNumericValue(charVal); 
            }
            System.out.println("La somme des chiffres est : "+somme);
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("You didn't enter an Integer Value");
        }
    }
}
```

Apparently, this is not the way it should have been done. Even though I won't get points taken off by doing it this way.

There is a simpler way **using only an integer without converting or cast to another type**
Do anyone know how to accomplish this task ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator and make use of integer division:

```
int sum = 0;

while (n > 0) {
    sum += n % 10;
    n /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, `for` is a better fit here?

Comment: @lifus: `for (;n; n /= 10)`?

Comment: that's right, `for(; n > 0; n /= 10)` just to make it copy/pastable.

Comment: @lifus: I would not put that in my code. The `while` loop is much clearer.

Comment: @lifus and @Blender for loops usually take a minimum of 3 parameters ... the starting point , the expression and the counter ... I have never seen a for loop start with : `for(; expression; counter)` I don't what you are trying to say,

Comment: @hayonj: It's a valid `for` loop. `for (;;)` is also a valid loop.

Comment: @Blender What is nothing supposed to mean ?

Comment: @hayonj: There's no initialization, there's no condition and there's no increment. It's an infinite loop.

Comment: @Blender the While loop here is really Amazingly... I don't understand why, I spent over an hour to find a solution and didn't think about this one ... It's so simple and I never saw it coming. Props to you for enlightening me on this one. It's so much better than my solution. Thank you.

Comment: The `while` loop conditional should be `(n > 0)`.

Comment: @Blender so how does this make any sense ? `for(; n > 0; n /= 10)` ?

Comment: @BLuFeNiX: Why shouldn't it make sense? The only thing it doesn't have is a variable initialization, which isn't needed when `n` has already been initialized and defined.

Comment: Any conditional must be a boolean statement. A number is not a statement that can mean `true` or `false`. You must compare it to something.

Comment: @Blender This example is perfect if the constraint was to read the number right to left and calculate the sum of each digit. But What if I wanted to read from leftto right say something like this ... This number i.e **54321** has 5 digits ... so 5 * 10000 ; 4 * 1000 ; 3 * 100 ; 2 * 10 ; 1 * 1 ; ... how would you do that since you can't really use the method **.length()** on an int ... can you write up the algorithm below as a new answer please ?

Comment: @hayonj, "This number i.e 54321 has 5 digits ... so 5 * 10000 ; 4 * 1000 ; 3 * 100 ; 2 * 10 ; 1 * 1 ;" ... summing up the numbers in this way will result in the original number, so I don't know why you would want to do that. As for finding the length of an `int`, do this: `new String(54321).length()`

Comment: @hayonj: I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Blender this is the proper way to do this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Question8Simple {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.print("Entrez un nombre entier : ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nb = in.nextInt();
        in.close();
        int sum = 0;

        while (nb>=1) {
            sum += nb % 10;
            nb /= 10;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

}
```

@BLuFeNiX I saw that. The loop wouldn't work without an expression. Weird !